# col-lg-8 not using 8/12ths of the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi all I'm using this bit of code

```
<section id="post1">
<div class="container-fluid post-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-8 oblongbig">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="=col-lg-6 oblong">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 oblong">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

to create three boxes, have a look at http://deliciousproductions.com.au

My problem is that the first and larger box is fine but the second two boxes should start after the first col-lg-8, but they just start right up against the large box, as though there's no padding/margin. I added a 10px margin so it's easier to understand. So the col-lg-8 isn't making it's width 8/12's of the screen?

The 2 boxes in rows also aren't responsive, they are but when you make the page smaller this happens: https://gyazo.com/4929147de70b0a88ac54d29f4ff2c243

and then finally: gyazo[.]com/c57374233a4e0f14fc4f757841893cc5

What would you recommend to make it so when the page resizes the 2 smaller boxes resize so they fit next to each horizontally under the larger box. This is for a blog style site btw.

cheers, Nik

here's the css for each box too

```
.oblongbig {
float: left;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #050505;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
margin: 10px;
```

}

```
.oblongbig:hover, .oblong:hover {
background-color: #121212;
```

}

```
.oblong {
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #050505;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
margin: 10px;
```

}

similar to this: [demo](http://demo.angelostudio.net/stellashop/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem with your grid code. Use this one

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div style="height:330px;background:#000;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div style="height:150px;background:#000;margin-bottom:30px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div style="height:150px;background:#000;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also don't apply styles directly on grid column. Place content div inside grid column and apply whichever styles you want on that div.

Check out this URL for better understanding of Bootstrap grid system - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-system.php

Answer (score 0):

To count a column you need to consider the value of the intervals between them. 
[Here you can see a visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mip6s.jpg)

Comment: wait so you can have a bigger row than col-12?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues going on in your code. For Bootstrap columns to work properly, you can't have a column div inside another column div without starting a row. For example, you must format it like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
      </div><!-- .row -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div>
```

In your example you have two nested columns with no row in between. This will mess up your column padding & margins.

Refer to the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Next, you're applying your own classes (.oblong, .oblongbig) with set float, fixed width, and margin to the Bootstrap column div. These are overriding the Bootstrap styles and preventing your columns from working properly.

The best idea is to use elements with Bootstrap classes to build your layout, then put elements **inside** these layout elements with your own custom classes. For example:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="oblong">Your content here, separate from the Bootstrap element</div>
</div>
```

Avoid overriding the framework's styles, as this results in confusing code. Once you reformat your code so that columns are correctly nested and you're not overriding the Bootstrap classes with your own custom widths, it should come together how you want.